# Nexus3 rebuild index error

Tags: nexus3

I use docker-nexus 3. When I rebuild  index maven repository It show success, but I search some common jar, it cannot come out nothing. How to synchronize the maven repository indexes to nexus 3?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for Browse Remote, it will not work. Nexus Repository Manager UI search only looks at cached or hosted content. If you feel strongly about this, please head to our JIRA: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS and file an issue. Thanks!